# How can I filter null values from this list?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I have the following procedure for creating all prime-pairs in a list:

```
(define (prime-pairs lst)
  (define (split lst pos)
    (list (drop-right lst pos) (take-right lst pos)))
  (define (prime-pairs-iter n acc)
    (cond ((= n 0) (filter (lambda (e) (not (null? e))) acc))
          (else (prime-pairs-iter (- n 1) 
                                  (let ((s (split lst n)))
                                    (if (and (prime? (list->number (car s)))
                                             (prime? (list->number (cadr s))))
                                        (append s acc)
                                        acc))))))
  (prime-pairs-iter (- (length lst) 1) '()))
```

(Full code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b8cfcb0bf021be9ef9c8)

What I want `prime-pairs` to do is create a list of every pair in the `lst` that consists of two primes. The numbers are represented in a list format as follows: 11 would be `'(1 1)`.

Unfortunately, when I run this code the `(filter (lambda (e) (not (null? e))) acc))` does not seem to remove the `'()` from the end result, and I end up with a long list of empty values and the wanted pairs.

If I use a `(filter null? acc))` a list of empty values does remain. So the other way around (filtering out the actual values) does work.

How can I filter out the nulls of the returned list?

Comment: Can you provide an example of this behavior?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, download the Gist that the OP has posted, and run it in a DrRacket instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `prime-pairs` function always returns one value: either an empty list, or the prime pairs. Using `map`, there is no way to avoid the empty lists, without doing further filtering on the result of the `map`.

One alternative is to return a *list* of results, and use `append-map` instead of `map`. Change your `prime-pairs` to return either an empty list, or *a singleton list* containing your prime pairs; this simulates returning zero or one value, rather than always one value. Like so:

```
(cond ((zero? n) (if (null? acc)
                     '()
                     (list acc)))
      ...)
```

Now, use `append-map`:

```
(append-map prime-pairs primes-list-split)
```

and you should have the results you seek. (See [my forked gist](https://gist.github.com/cky/2d6886fe5f7cbec9def8) for full code.)

Comment: At first I didn't understand why in your answer `append-map` did filter out the nulls, and `map` didn't. Turns out that the difference between `append-map` and `map` is that `append-map` uses `append`, and `map` uses `cons` to concatenate the results of applying the procedure to the elements ([source](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Mapping-of-Lists.html)). Appending null to a list results in the list, consing null to a list results in the list plus null. So that explains why appending leads to a result with the nulls filtered out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am having some other trouble with the method. I created a new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998531/how-to-generate-list-of-prime-pairs-that-can-be-concatenated-to-new-prime.