# How to generate list of prime pairs that can be concatenated to new prime?

Tags: scheme

I have a list of primes stored in a variable `primes-list-split` that are represented in a list format by a `number->list` method. The format is as follows: the prime list of 2, 3, 5, 7, and 11 would be `'((2) (3) (5) (7) (1 1))`.

`get-prime-pairs` takes as input this list, and tries to find every combination that concatenates to another prime. Then it should return these pairs in a list in the list representation. So the pair 3 367 which concatenates to 3367 which is also prime should be in the list in the representation ((3) (3 6 7)).

To achieve this my idea was to walk over the list and for every prime represented as a list concatenate it with all other primes represented as lists. If the combined list representation is also prime after a conversion to a number via the `list->number` method I add it to the final list which is returned.

The code is implemented as follows:

```
(define (prime? n)
  (define (check-divisible n divisor)
    (cond ((= divisor 1) #t)
          ((= 0 (modulo n divisor)) #f)
          (else (check-divisible n (- divisor 1)))))
  (cond ((<= n 1) #f)
        ((= n 2) #t)
        ((even? n) #f)
        (else (check-divisible n (truncate (sqrt n))))))

; Copyright (C) 2011 Toby Thain, toby@telegraphics.com.au
(define (primes-up-to n)
  (let ((sieve (make-vector (+ n 1) #t)))
    (define (test-prime i)
      (define (is-prime? idx)
        (vector-ref sieve idx))
      (define (not-prime! idx)
        (vector-set! sieve idx #f))
      (define (remove-multiples i step)
        (when (<= i n)
          (not-prime! i)
          (remove-multiples (+ i step) step)))
      (if (> i n)
          '()
          (if (is-prime? i)
              (begin
                (remove-multiples i i)
                (cons i (test-prime (+ i 1))))
              (test-prime (+ i 1)))))
    (test-prime 2)))

(define primes-list (primes-up-to 100000))


;; From list generate split arrays of allowed pairs

; www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12834562/scheme-number-to-list#12841962
(define (number->list n)
  (let loop ((n n) (acc '()))
    (if (< n 10)
        (cons n acc)
        (loop (quotient n 10)
              (cons (remainder n 10) acc)))))

; www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1683479/how-to-convert-a-list-to-num-in-scheme#1688960
(define (list->number lst)
  (let loop ((n 0) (lst lst))
    (if (empty? lst)
        n
        (loop (+ (* 10 n) (car lst)) (cdr lst)))))

; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909685/how-can-i-filter-null-values-from-this-list
(define primes-list-split 
  (map number->list primes-list))

(define (get-prime-pairs lst)
  (define (split lst pos)
    (list (drop-right lst pos) (take-right lst pos)))
  (define (get-prime-pairs-iter n acc)
    (if (zero? n) 
        (if 
         (or (null? acc) 
             ; filter out those values that start with leading zero
             (zero? (caar acc)) 
             (zero? (caadr acc))) 
         '() 
         (list acc))
        (get-prime-pairs-iter 
         (- n 1) 
         (let ((s (split lst n)))
           (if (and (prime? (list->number (car s)))
                    (prime? (list->number (cadr s))))
               (append s acc)
               acc)))))
  (get-prime-pairs-iter (- (length lst) 1) '()))

(define split-array-of-allowed-pairs 
  (append-map get-prime-pairs primes-list-split))

split-array-of-allowed-pairs
```

Unfortunately, sometimes it returns 'pairs' that contains of four or more values. For example, `split-array-of-allowed-pairs` contains pairs like this:

```
((...)
((3) (6 4 3))
((3) (6 5 9))
((3 6 7) (3) (3) (6 7 3))
((3 6 7) (7) (3) (6 7 7))
(...))
```

We see here that longer combinations are returned. I want `((3 6 7) (3))` and `((3) (3 6 7))` to be both represented separately as a pair of two. Somehow they end up combined.

What is wrong in my method and does anyone know how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

See the gist here for the code with two tests below that should both return true: https://gist.github.com/erooijak/2d462ad429e6e05ddd25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `get-prime-pairs` has several problems. Here is a working, non-tail recursive version:

```
(define (get-prime-pairs lst)
  (define (find-all-prime-pairs prime lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (if (prime? (list->number (append prime (car lst))))
            (cons (list prime (car lst))
                  (find-all-prime-pairs prime (cdr lst)))
            (find-all-prime-pairs prime (cdr lst)))))
  (append-map (lambda (x) (find-all-prime-pairs x lst)) lst))

(define split-array-of-allowed-pairs (get-prime-pairs primes-list-split))
```

Here is how it works.

The function `get-prime-pairs` tries for all the element of list `lst` to combine them with all the elements of list, by calling the function `find-all-prime-pairs`.

The auxiliary function `find-all-prime-pairs` tries to combine its first argument (`prime`) with all the elements of the list second argument (`lst`), and returns all the pairs where the combination is a prime number. In this case the recursion is on the second argument, `lst`: if it is empty, then no pair can be found, otherwise it appends `prime` to the `car` of `lst` to see if this is a prime number. If this is true then the function returns the list obtained by the first pair and the result of the recursive call to the rest of `lst`, otherwise it returns simply the result of the recursive call.

It seems to me that the main problem for which your recursion does not work is that writing a recursive function as tail-recursive as first try is not the best way to get it correct. So, I dare to suggest you to consider the foundamental rule of programming:

> First, make your program *work*, then, and if it necessary, make it efficient.

In other words, I suggest you first to write the function as a "normal" recursive function, and then, when you are sure that it works, rewrite it as tail recursive (or iterative) if necessary (and in the above case this is left as an exercise).

As final note, consider that 3367 is not a prime number, being equal to 7 * 13 * 37.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice and help regarding the code. I was stuck on this and am grateful you have helped me out. Also thanks for leaving something as an exercise. :-) And indeed, 3367 should have been 3673.

Comment: Somehow your algorithm misses a lot of valid pairs (e.g., `'((1 1) (3))`; `'((6 7 3) (3))`); . My current suspicion is that the combinations where the second value is lower than the first are missed.

Comment: Suspicion was right. I did not know how to fix it in above code, so I added another method which loops over the list produced by your method, checks if the opposite is also a pair and if so adds it to a resulting list. It ain't pretty, but at least I have the full list now. Extra method can be found in comment below. I believe I do need an accumulator so I do not know how to not use an iterative/tail-recursive process.

Comment: `(define (add-opposite-prime-pairs prime-pairs)
  (define (add-opposite-prime-pairs-iter lst acc)
    (cond ((null? lst) acc)
          ((prime? (list->number (append (cadar lst) (caar lst))))
           (add-opposite-prime-pairs-iter (cdr lst) (cons (append (cdar lst) (list (caar lst))) acc)))
          (else (add-opposite-prime-pairs-iter (cdr lst) acc))))
  (add-opposite-prime-pairs-iter prime-pairs prime-pairs))`

Comment: You are right! I was missing half of the pairs! I (hope to) have corrected the algorithm.

Comment: There is also space for other optimizations, as well, in particular `find-all-prime-pairs` can be rewritten in tail-recursive way.

Comment: Hi Renzo, thanks :-). My method of looping over the whole list was way too slow for the particular problem I am solving. What is the advantage of using tail recursion? Is it quicker in time or only in space?

Comment: It is quicker both in time as well as in space. Since it is transformed in a loop, the stack is not used, and the recursive call becomes a loop. Another optimization should concern the test for primality, you should use the sieve not only to generate the list of primes, but also to test, instead of using `prime?`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87027/discussion-between-erwin-rooijakkers-and-renzo).

Answer (score -1):

```
public class PrimeConcatenation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s1=new  Scanner(System.in);
        int num =s1.nextInt();
        int[] arr=new int[num];
        int[] res;
        int index=0;
        int count=0;
        for (int i = 2; i <=num; i++) {            
            if(prime(i))
            {
                arr[index]=i;
                index++;
//              System.out.println(""+i+""+prime(i));  
            }            
        }
        res=new int[index*index];
        int res_index=0;        
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<index;j++)
            {
                String str=""+arr[i]+arr[j];
                if(prime(Integer.parseInt(str)))
                {
//                    System.out.println("val is "+str);
                    res[res_index]=Integer.parseInt(str);
                    res_index++;
                    count++;
                }                
            }
        }
        System.out.println(""+count);        
    }
    static boolean prime(int num)
    {
        boolean res;
        for(int i=2;i<num;i++)
        {
            if(num%i==0)
            {
                res=false;
                return res;
            }            
        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```